# Restrict Access to External API by IP's - SBX IP's not published, Manage IP changes

Tags: rest-api, api, ip-whitelisting, restriction

We are have a Rest API that we need to call from SF and must restrict access to specific IP's.
Our Production Org is hosted on USA286.  Using a callout to api.ipify.org we were able to determine traffic was originating from 3 IP's - 35.80.213.208, 35.161.141.162, & 44.234.249.148.
These are published in the [Salesforce IP Addresses and Domains to Allow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384438&type=1) article at the bottom in May 19, 2021 Revision Under US-West (Public Cloud).

We used the same process on our Dev and Partial Copy Sandboxes, but could not find the IP's listed in the article.  Our Dev SBX is hosted on USA28S and the IP's it is using are - 52.40.154.108, 52.43.157.174, 44.241.73.113. Is there a reason these are not published?

We have whitelisted the 3 IP's for each of our orgs and are able to connect to our Server.  However I am concerned with the stability - if SF changes the IP's we loose connection.
My thought was to build an Apex Class that runs daily to call api.ipify.org (see below).  I would create a Custom Metadata a record for each Org and store the IPs.  If the IP's retuned from api.ipify.org do not Metadata then I will send an email to the Admin team.  Of course we will need to update the Metadata if we add/refresh Sandboxes.

Does this seem like a reasonable approach or does someone have a better way?

```
    HttpRequest reqIp = new HttpRequest();
    reqIp.setEndpoint('https://api.ipify.org');
    reqIp.setMethod('GET');
    Http httpReq = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(reqIp);

    Http httpIp = new Http();
        System.Debug('reqIp = ' + reqIp);
    HTTPResponse responseIp = httpIp.send(reqIp);
        System.Debug('responseIp = ' + String.valueOf(responseIp.getBody()));
```

Comment: Note that Hyperforce documentation says that IP allow listing is no longer recommended as the IPs change without notice.

Comment: Thanks!  It would have saved me a lot of time if I actually read the whole article instead of jumping right to the IP's.  I found the link to the Hyperforce IP's and passed these along to my IT Team.  
I also passed on SF recommended alternatives to white listing - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394078&type=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Hyperforce Section of Salesforce IP Addresses and Domains to Allow:

> If you have a business or compliance need to maintain IP allowlists on
> Hyperforce, [Hyperforce External IPs](https://compliance.salesforce.com/en/documents/a006e0000121zduAAA) contains IPs for connection from
> Salesforce to the customer's network for products built on the
> Salesforce platform

The the secure link has a download with a list of 147 IP's
However it also includes a whitepaper which states

> Salesforce provides Hyperforce IPs for customers who have an
> insurmountable business or compliance requirement for IP allowlisting,
> or who need extra time to convert to modern security practices such as
> those described in ﻿ [Preferred Alternatives to IP Allowlisting on
> Hyperforce﻿](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394078&language=en_US&type=1).